# Can't find class element using document.queryselector all

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get a specific element by its class.

Here is the element:

```
<div id="getticketspecifictext-13827" class="ms-Panel-contentInner ms-Panel-tickets13827">
```

Here is the code. It fails at line 4 when trying to find the element in question:

```
const outputd = document.getElementById(paneltextinsert);
console.log(outputd)
console.log("ms-Panel-tickets" + ticketid)
var PanelExampleseditticket = document.getElementsByClassName(".ms-Panel-contentInner .ms-Panel-tickets" + ticketid);
console.log(PanelExampleseditticket)
PanelExampleeditticket = PanelExampleseditticket.querySelector(outputd.id);
console.log(editticketbutton.id)
console.log(PanelExampleeditticket)
var PanelExamplePaneleditticket = PanelExampleseditticket.querySelector(".freshdeskpanel");
console.log(PanelExamplePaneleditticket)
PanelExampleeditticket.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
  new fabric['Panel'](PanelExamplePaneleditticket);
});
```

I tried also looking for just `ms-Panel-tickets"+ticketid` but it wouldn't find it even though if I printed the id it works perfectly.

[image]

EDIT: I tried taking out the space between the two classes I was looking for and that didn't work. Like so:

```
".ms-Panel-contentInner.ms-Panel-tickets"+ticketid
```

I also tried just using `.ms-Panel-tickets"+ticketid` as well and it still can't be found.

Comment: The problem is that `PanelExampleseditticket` is null. You forgot to put a `#` before `outputd.id` when calling `querySelector()`

Comment: Your code doesn't use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Try removing the space between the two classes you specify, i.e instead of `.ms-Panel-contentInner .ms-Panel-tickets` try `.ms-Panel-contentInner.ms-Panel-tickets`

Comment: You don't use `.` prefixes when calling `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Why do you need to search for the element by ID when you already have the element in the `outputd` variable?

Comment: You're passing a selector to `getElementsByClassName`. Use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: taking out the `.` did the trick. I thought I did that already. maybe I accidently had a `#` in there. Thank you for double checking. Also to answer your question. I already tried outputd but it was still giving me the same issue. So I tried work around the issue by finding the element based on the class I gave it. I will try outputd again. Maybe I had typed it wrong. Thanks again everyone for the quick help

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `.` when calling `getElementByClassName`. It should be more like this:

```
var PanelExampleseditticket = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Panel-contentInner ms-Panel-tickets" + ticketid);
```